# Postgis ST_AsSVG renders a tiny SVG

Tags: postgis, linestring, svg

I am storing information about a person's journey as a linestring.

Having recently discovered ST_AsSVG I tried the following query:

```
SELECT
ST_AsSVG(path)
```

FROM
    activities
WHERE
    id = 209

Which produces the path data as expexted. When i put that in to an SVG the path is exceptionally small and way off the "canvas"

See the SVG code here:

https://gist.github.com/FearMediocrity/0969b7324689a1879585

Does anyone have any suggestions to make the output more useable?

Comment: Might [this](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) be of any help?